# Command line option to download file in FileZilla

Tags: windows, command-line-arguments, filezilla

I am using FileZilla (GUI) to download files from an FTP server. Can any one tell me a command line argument to download file from FTP server to local file system?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

FileZilla does not have any command line arguments (nor any other way) that allow automatic transfer.

See:
[FileZilla Client command-line arguments](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Command-line_arguments_(Client))
https://trac.filezilla-project.org/ticket/2317

---

Though you can use any other FTP client that allows automation.

- Built-it Windows [`ftp.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftp) (use its `get` command).

  Though Windows `ftp.exe` does not support a passive mode, what makes it useless nowadays, when connecting over Internet due to ubiquitous firewalls and NATs.
- WinSCP: You can automatically make it download a file both in GUI and scripting mode

  - GUI:

    ```
    winscp.exe ftp://user:password@host/path/file.ext
    ```

    You will get a dialog, where you select a directory to download the file to.

    See https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline
  - Scripting (put the command to a `.bat` file):

    ```
    winscp.com /command ^  
        "open ftp://user:password@host/" ^  
        "get /path/file.ext c:\" ^  
        "exit"
    ```

    See https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation
  - The WinSCP can even [generate a script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#generating) from an [imported FileZilla session](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_import).

    For details, see a [guide to FileZilla automation](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_filezilla_automation).

    *(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Answer (score -4):

FileZilla does support some basic command line options for the upload and download of files. Not all options are documented.
You can download a file with the option "-d *sourcefile* *targetdir*"

**Example (download):**

```
filezilla.exe -d ftp://user:pass@ftp.myserver.com/folder/* "c:\downloads\" ​ /overwrite /close
```

**Example (upload):**

```
filezilla.exe -u "c:\temp\samplefile.exe" ​ftp://user:pass@ftp.myserver.com/folder /overwrite /close
```

/close -- will close the GUI after the download/upload completes

/overwrite -- will overwrite the files in target without prompting the user

You can also connect to a site from the site manager e.g. --site="0/site1".

Below are reference sites with further examples including download links to FileZilla versions (2.32 / 3.1) that supported the feature.

[FAQ Link](ftp://ftp.onyxgfx.net/pub/FileZilla/Filezilla.txt)

[FileZilla Download link](ftp://ftp.onyxgfx.net/pub/FileZilla/)

Comment: I tried these out and FileZilla reports that -u and -d are "Unknown Options". My software is also up to date.  Is this an addon?

Comment: @PowerUser Try to download from here ftp://ftp.onyxgfx.net/pub/FileZilla/FileZilla_2_2_32_setup.exe . It supports the -d and -u options.

Comment: FileZilla 2.2.32 is over 10 years old. Please, do not suggest anyone to use it!

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I am just referring to the version and the FAQ link explaining about those command line options. Some people may still find it useful.