# Use FileZilla FTP client to download large amount of files with specific websites

Tags: ftp, filezilla

We have a list of websites of files to download like these:

```
ftp://aaa.bbb.ccc/folder1/file0111.dat
ftp://aaa.bbb.ccc/folder2/file0234.dat
ftp://aaa.bbb.ccc/folder5/file1987.dat
...
ftp://aaa.bbb.ccc/folder9/fileXXYY.dat
```

The file amount is too large, say 1000, we could not select them one by one.
Therefore, we plan to put the websites into a text file, say `website.txt`, 
then use FilleZilla to download all the dat files with `website.txt`.

Can FileZilla do like this?

Thanks a lot!
Kindly, EmanLee

Answer (score 2):

You can make an queue.xml file and Filezilla will download those files in that xml.
Here is an example from the Export Method, you would have to import it to Filezilla. File-> Export/Import

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FileZilla3 version="3.14.1" platform="windows">
    <Queue>
        <Server>
            <Host>ftp.site.com</Host>
            <Port>21</Port>
            <Protocol>0</Protocol>
            <Type>0</Type>
            <User>ftp.site.com|CORP\user</User>
            <Pass encoding="base64">XXXX</Pass>
            <Logontype>1</Logontype>
            <TimezoneOffset>0</TimezoneOffset>
            <PasvMode>MODE_DEFAULT</PasvMode>
            <MaximumMultipleConnections>0</MaximumMultipleConnections>
            <EncodingType>Auto</EncodingType>
            <BypassProxy>0</BypassProxy>
            <Name>SiteName</Name>
            <File>
                <LocalFile>C:\XXX.txt</LocalFile>
                <RemoteFile>XXX.txt</RemoteFile>
                <RemotePath>1 0</RemotePath>
                <Download>0</Download>
                <Size>635529</Size>
                <DataType>0</DataType>
            </File>
        </Server>
    </Queue>
</FileZilla3>
```

https://trac.filezilla-project.org/ticket/4905

Answer (score 0):

FileZilla does not support scripting:
[Command line option to download file in FileZilla](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28022567/850848)

---

You can use [WinSCP scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation) to download list of files.

For example, you can create a batch file (`get.bat`) like:

```
@echo off

winscp.com /command ^
    "open ""%1""" ^
    "get ""%2""" ^
    "exit"
```

And than you call it like this from another batch file:

```
@echo off

call get.bat ftp://aaa.bbb.ccc/folder1/ file0111.dat
call get.bat ftp://aaa.bbb.ccc/folder2/ file0234.dat
call get.bat ftp://aaa.bbb.ccc/folder5/ file1987.dat
...
call get.bat ftp://aaa.bbb.ccc/folder9/ fileXXYY.dat
```

---

See also [Upload to multiple servers / Parametrized script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_upload_multiple_servers). Though to avoid confusion, note that my answer does not use the technique described in the article.

Comment: Thanks! I am working on Windows 7 platform and downloading files by mulitiple-threading way.

Comment: You can split the master batch file to say three sets and run them in parallel (from a super-master batch file using `start` command).

Comment: And if you run the `winscp.com /command "open" ...` manually from command-line?

Comment: I ran `winscp.com /command     "open ""ftp://ftp.xaut.edu.cn/RG-VPN/"""     "get ""RG-WALL_3.1.3.0.zip"""     "exit"`   from command-line. It did not work.

Comment: If you add `/log=log.log`, is the log created?

Comment: I get an username prompt, when I use your exact command: `Prompting for credentials...` ... `Username: Authentication failed.`

Comment: Please try this `winscp.com /command     "open ""ftp://ftp-trace.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sra/sra-instant/reads/ByStudy/sra/SRP/SRP000/SRP000941/SRR1045839/"""     "get ""SRR1045839.sra"""     "exit"` This does not need credentials.

Comment: Another test:  [link](http://www.ibiomedical.net/plek/temp_snap2.png) It did not say OK or Fail.

Comment: That was not my point. My point was that it does start connecting. So the syntax is correct. Even you screenshots is strange. It just does not do anything. I've never seen such problem. Can you try `winscp.exe /console`?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `wget -i website.txt`

Comment: Please provide more details. What should be inside website.txt ?

Comment: See original question - a list of URLs to be downloaded.