# Connect Filezilla and Pycharm

Tags: pycharm, filezilla

Am working on Pycharm community and would like to add Filezilla as command sftp to automate some upload tasks.

Is there a way to connect both software, so I can upload to server easily.
(ie without opening filezilla and do it manually).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command line option to download file in FileZilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28022567/command-line-option-to-download-file-in-filezilla)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [Deployment](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2017.1/deployment.html) possibility of the PyCharm? I don't think it would be possible to somehow connect FileZilla and PyCharm. And if you would like to upload/deploy something, then built-in functionality should be prefered.